# Deadlock And Select for update

Tags: mysql, database

Query Q1. select * from table where id = 1;
Query Q2. select * from table where unique_id = "x";

If both **return same row** is deadlock still possible?

THREAD T1.

```
BEGIN
select * from table where id = 1 for update;
update ... table where id = 1;
Commit;
```

THREAD T2.

```
BEGIN
select * from table where unique_id = "x" for update;
update ... table where id = 1;// updating with id=1
Commit;
```

Assume T1 and T2 called concurrently.

Is this cause deadlock? Is there any issue if we use different "where condition" in the query even if it return same row.

Tried with select for update in most cases its working but found issue if i use different where condition in update query

Answer (score 0):

Yes a deadlock is possible.

Use the SKIP LOCKED option which is available in [MySQL-8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) and [MariaDB-10.6+](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/#skip-locked) to avoid them selecting the same row.